# Downloading numpy module for python

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone tell me how I can install the numpy module for python. Since I have so little knowledge of installing modules, I would also like to know in what directory I'll have to store it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use pip. I suggest you do a quick google search on pip, but basically its running `pip install numpy`from the command line or terminal.

Comment: In addition, it will installed under the python version under which the pip was installed with. Take note when installing for python3, use `pip3` and python2, use `pip`.

Comment: Yes, that is what have tried. Unfortunantely it did not work, so I guess because of the location I put it in. I tried storing it in the Python36/Scripts directory. Might that be the reason?

Comment: `because of the location I put it in` What "it" do you mean?  pip itself, or the numpy package?

Comment: You could install anaconda as well, I believe they have binaries available for easy installation.

Comment: I was talking about the numpy package.

Comment: Numpy comes with anaconda, along with other useful modules.

Comment: @user7550785 Are you using PyCharm? You can install python library direct from IDE.